# Python urllib2 automatic form filling and retrieval of results

Tags: python, forms, automation, urllib2, urllib

I'm looking to be able to query a site for warranty information on a machine that this script would be running on.  It should be able to fill out a form if needed ( like in the case of say HP's service site) and would then be able to retrieve the resulting web page.

I already have the bits in place to parse the resulting html that is reported back I'm just having trouble with what needs to be done in order to do a POST of data that needs to be put in the fields and then being able to retrieve the resulting page.

Answer (score 16):

If you absolutely **need** to use urllib2, the basic gist is this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://whatever.foo/form.html'
form_data = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
```

If you send along POST data (the 2nd argument to `urlopen()`), the request method is automatically set to POST.

I suggest you do yourself a favor and use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), a full-blown urllib2 replacement that acts exactly like a real browser. A lot of sites use hidden fields, cookies, and redirects, none of which urllib2 handles for you by default, where mechanize does.

Check out [Emulating a browser in Python with mechanize](http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/) for a good example.

Comment: I will also put in a vote for mechanize. I have used it a number of times. Really useful and much easier than urllib and urllib2 for doing complex things.

Comment: I agree. Mechanize is the standard tool for doing this. Don't use urllib2 unless you absolutely must.

Answer (score 1):

Using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) together,

```
data = urllib.urlencode([('field1',val1), ('field2',val2)]) # list of two-element tuples
content = urllib2.urlopen('post-url', data)
```

content will give you the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve only done a little bit of this, but:

1. You’ve got the HTML of the form page. Extract the `name` attribute for each form field you need to fill in.
2. Create a dictionary mapping the names of each form field with the values you want submit.
3. Use `urllib.urlencode` to turn the dictionary into the body of your post request.
4. Include this encoded data as the second argument to `urllib2.Request()`, after the URL that the form should be submitted to.

The server will either return a resulting web page, or return a redirect to a resulting web page. If it does the latter, you’ll need to issue a `GET` request to the URL specified in the redirect response.

I hope that makes some sort of sense?