# Can't post to proxy form

Tags: python, post, urllib2

I want to use urllib2 through a proxy http site, post to the form component having name="what", click submit, and return the resulting webpage as a string. I know many have asked this question before, see [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667699/python-urllib2-automatic-form-filling-and-retrieval-of-results). However, I couldn't get their solutions to work for my example code below:

```
url = "http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html"
posturl = "www.google.ca"
values = {'what':posturl}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()

print html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

piggybacking on Christian's answer:

`requests` is a very good library for this stuff... however, `urllib2` also suffices:

```
import urllib2


def get_anon_content(url):
    anon_url = 'http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/%s' % url
    req = urllib2.Request(anon_url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = response.read()
    return content


url = 'http://www.google.ca'
print get_anon_content(url)
```

Comment: maybe I was not clear. I don't want to load a single url. I want to post the url to the form, submit, and get the result as a string. Obviously using anonymouse was a bad example.

Answer (score 0):

in youre case you can just use this url:

http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://www.google.ca

its the same thing as using anonymouse except you dont have to go to the site you just use the url

and next time make it easier on youreself and use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) you can get the same effect of urllib but with like 4 lines so check that out

and good luck :)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question. How do I use requests to post the google link to anonymouse?